# What should I expect from a position that requires extensive travel?

Tags: new-job, united-states, travel

I accepted a position that requires 70% travel. This is the first role I've taken that require any traveling. Not much details were given to me other than traveling to client locations via flight throughout the US.

I'd appreciate some tips and feedback from others who've held position requiring such extensive traveling.

Comment: They're the only ones who know exactly what that means. It's really something you should've clarified during the interview stage, if it matters to you. I'd interpret 70% travel as "70% of working time spent at clients" (although I'm not saying that's what they meant by it), but that could mean you're spending a few continuous months at a single client or it could mean you're flying back and forth daily.

Comment: Point taken. I guess I was wanting others experience with extensive traveling.

Comment: I have travelling duties at work, often requiring 04:00am starts. Also you might face jet lag or not?

Comment: I've put this on hold as too broad.  (The other four votes were for off-topic because you seemed to be asking about company-specific rules.)  Asking for people's experiences with travel is too broad to work well for our site.  Questions that are more specific, like how to manage some of the logistics, would be better fits.

Comment: It's not international so no jet lack

Comment: @Noah, red-eye from West Coast to East can be pretty rough.  I wouldn't rule out jet lag

Comment: @Joe, from what they explained to me, seems like once a client purchases their product, I would be sent out to set up their system and do training. The client acquisition frequency would determine my travel rate. They stated UP TO 70% so I guess that would be the max.

Comment: @Joe, I do some traveling but mostly vacation which involve international flights. NEVER flown domestic. I love the company and it's a fortune 100. I might also add that I would not be traveling alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I accepted a position that requires 70% travel

My wife has one of these positions, and the best advice I can give to you is make sure **your travel occurs through the week** and does not cut into any part of your weekend.  *That is your time*, and with traveling that much for your career you're going to need it.

Hopefully you have a **company credit card to ease the burden of filing expense** reports too.

Another way to look how long you will be gone: you're going to be gone close to **5 out of 7 days** in a week.

Comment: I will be given company issued credit card and all travel expenses paid. May I ask how your wife felt about the travel?

Comment: @Noah It was fun at first, but got old as she missed stuff with the kids.  It got way easier when the weekends were not impacted.  She flies out on Mondays and is back friday early afternoon.

Comment: I think I might've sealed my fate than. I was told weekends as well. When you've been unemployed for 8 months and bills piling up......Hopefully I'll be able to move up in the chain

Comment: @Noah sometimes you have to do what you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a role which required extensive travel - it was fun, but I could never plan weekends, or any family event, as I never knew what city or country I might need to be in. If you are single, this may be fun, but if you have a family it may suck.

Speed of expenses was the critical factor for survival, not pay day.

Ask them for more detail.

Comment: Ha -- this is a lot like my answer!

Comment: LOL - sadly we had a company credit card which made the burden of expenses much worse as it delayed every payment, booking charges within Amex were not claimable and the liability was employee owned, so I by the time I left that role I was just over £1000 worse off than if I had used my own card.

Comment: I do have guaranteed one month vacation and 10 holidays so I guess I'm looking at 10 months or so of work and 7 months of traveling. I am single by the way. Once I settle down, I will probably move on.